# SQL update query does not update database

Tags: php, mysql

This is an edit profile portion of the website I'm making but now I can't make it work. I have a jquery form and then processed by php.

```
$("#editButton").click(function(){
                $.post("editprofile.php",
                {
                    fname: $("#fnameBox").val(),
                    lname: $("#lnameBox").val(),
                    contact: $("#contactBox").val()
                },
                function(data){
                  alert(data);
                });
            });
```

I'm pretty sure the jquery part works because I have one doing change password.

So here's the php code

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","accting");
    $query = "Select * from users where username='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        $array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];

    $query = "UPDATE users SET firstname='{$fname}', lastname='{$lname}', contactNumber='{$contact}' WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    echo "Edit profile successful.";
?>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Any errors/warnings at any point in the code?

Comment: SQL injection warning. Also, after mysqli_query, echo out mysqli_error to see what the error is if there was one.

Comment: change `alert(data)` to `console.log(data)` and see what you get back. You **should** get back "Edit profile successful." regardless of whether that's true or not - if you don't, you've probably got a syntax or parse error in your PHP. On another note, what are you using the first $query, $result and $array for? They look pretty unused and should be removed...

Comment: I used console.log(data), now it's not returning anything. Thanks for pointing out the unnecessary variables too, I just copied it from a php file I wrote earlier. Will trim em out at once.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn It alerted out a bunch of html code when I did that.

Answer (score 0):

WRONG COLUMN NAME.

My bad.

Sorry, first full-scale website I'm making. Will keep this in mind next time. Argh,